# Split a group of integers into two subgroups of approximately the same suns

Tags: r, split, cut, partition

I have a group of integers, as in this `R` `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("id",1:100), length = as.integer(runif(100,10000,1000000)), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So each element has an `id` and a `length`.

I'd like to split df into two `data.frame`s with approximately equal sums of `length`.

Any idea of an `R` function to achieve that?

I thought that `Hmisc`'s `cut2` might do it but I don't think that's its intended use:

```
library(Hmisc) # cut2
ll <- split(df, cut2(df$length, g=2))
> sum(ll[[1]]$length)
[1] 14702139
> sum(ll[[2]]$length)
[1] 37564671
```

Comment: With `g`, it is cutting into 2 quantile groups

Comment: If you're not after an optimized result, you could do something like `split(df, cumsum(df$length) < sum(df$length)/2)`.  Otherwise look into binpacking solvers that can optimize the split to be as even as possible.

Comment: if you randomize the rows of `df` and repeat @27ϕ9's method, you can get a more optimized solution: `dif <- Inf; max <- 50; while(dif > max) {tmp <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]; tmp <- split(tmp, cumsum(tmp$length) < sum(tmp$length)/2); dif <- abs(diff(sapply(tmp, function(x) sum(x$length))))}; dif` only takes a few seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called Bin pack problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem this link may be helpful.

Using `BBmisc::binPack` function,

```
df$bins <- binPack(df$length, sum(df$length)/2 + 1)
tapply(df$length, df$bins, sum)
```

results like

```
       1        2        3 
25019106 24994566    26346
```

Now since you want two groups,

```
dummy$bins[dummy$bins == 3] <- 2 #because labeled as 2's sum is smaller
```

result is

```
       1        2 
25019106 25020912
```

Comment: Just to mention that this is by far not an optimal solution. There is a split into two groups with sums `c(26133405, 26133405)`, that is the sums of items in each group are exactly the same. This can be found by applying a more powerful Bin Packing function available in R.